# JQuery Mobile input text / search layout when resized

Tags: jquery-mobile, layout, resize

I'm pretty new to JQuery Mobile (using v1.3.1) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have a `field-contain` div with a label and a text/search input in it. When I resize the window the following happens:

[image]

First the searchbox jumps onto a new line (I could live with that), but then when I resize it further, it eventually gets taller and covers the label (I obviously cannot live with that :P ).

Here's the code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="city-location">Location:</label>
  <input type="search" name="location" id="CheckCityNameInput" value="" data-mini="true"  data-inline="true" />
</div>
<input type="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" value="Locate city" data-mini="true"/>
```

This happens with Chrome and Firefox (I didn't test other browsers). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Also when I resize it to the max, a "line" appears between the text input and the button... any idea why?

Comment: Tell me jQuery Mobile version you are using?

Comment: It's in the post: 1.3.1

Comment: I should have better specify my question, I am wondering about your script location. This kind of problems usually happen when link to live production version is used. Try using this files: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js and http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css. If not we will think of something else.

Comment: Hum. That's the ones I am currently using >_<

Comment: I think I've found part of it. It seems to be conflicting CSS rules...

Comment: Ok lets do something else, I will not put it into answer until we fix it. First this is probably jQuery Mobile bug. From what I can see input height has suddenly become larger. You can inforce original height like this:     .ui-input-search { height: 30px !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Damn, it was a conflicting CSS rules on the labels. Good to know that a `float:left` rule on a label would have this effect though.

Thanks for your help Gajotres.